# How can i add which is run by 'Blah blah' on firefox address bar (Self signed SSL)

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I need to add which is run by text on firefox. Is it possible using self signed certificate. what are the steps i need to perform to achieve this ?

Eg:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text only appears for [Extended Validation certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).  Whether you can do that with a self-signed cert depends on whether you can get the browser to accept EV certs from your signing CA.