# How to change the "Secure" text from chrome ssl certificate next to url?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I see some website have changed the label on chromes ssl certificate, next to the url, from "Secure" to something else. Example: https://sunday.dk/ (Where the label is "Danske Bank A/S [DK]):
[image]

Comment: You need to buy a SSL certificate and register it to be able todo that. Like from Verisign.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6936587

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a particular type of SSL certificate called Extended Verification (EV)

> An Extended Validation Certificate (EV) is a certificate used for HTTPS websites and software that proves the legal entity controlling the website or software package. Obtaining an EV certificate requires verification of the requesting entity's identity by a certificate authority (CA).

Have a look on Google for "extended verification ssl certificates" and you'll find lots of providers who will sell you one.

As a word of warning, there is quite a bit of admin in order to get the certificate issued. If you're familiar with buying normal SSL certs then this is a quick process and is mostly automated and takes a few minutes. I have spent a couple of weeks going back and forth to get an EV.